# Angular Could not resolve dependency: zone.js

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, dependency-management

I have a stange error... Working with Angular and now suddenly I pulled some updated code and I can't even install the packages for my project anymore, I always get the following message:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
peer zone.js@"~0.10.3" from @angular/core@10.2.5
node_modules/@angular/core
@angular/core@"^10.1.5" from the root project
peer @angular/core@"10.2.5" from @angular/animations@10.2.5
node_modules/@angular/animations
dev @angular/animations@"^10.1.5" from the root project
```

It is strange because nothing changed, just removed the node_modules folder for making a clean install... I am using npm@7.11.2 and node@v14.15.4. And this is the content of the package.json (I know a lot of them old, I had to use them).

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
    "@okta/okta-angular": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-ripple": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.19.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.3",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-countdown": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-hocs-unsubscriber": "^1.1.7",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.11.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.6",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "0.0.1-alpha.32",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.4.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.6.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.6",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.8.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.1"
  }
```

Any help would be a big thanks, because this issue is killing my nerves....

Comment: Do you have any package-lock ? Can you reproduce it on someone else computer (by deleting the node_modules folder) ?

Comment: No .lock files, I don't like them :) Also I am the solo dev for this project, have no other dev nearby unfortunately.

Comment: Well, you `don't like them`, but are made exactly to avoid this kind of error. One of your lib must have been updated, and is no more compatible with the other ones... Looking at the message, it seems to be related to angular dependency... I think all you can do now is generate a new project, and pin-point any diference with your own package.json...

Comment: Well after somehow generating the exast lockfile for this project, the issue turned out to be hillarious.. the dev I replaced on this project, changed version for one package last minute and removed the lock ile from the remote repository.... IDK why. However some commit combing solved my issue.

Comment: Looks like sabotage haha. But Git always win.